# Is there any way to halt page load until an image is loaded(preloader)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image that I am using in  a preloader. I want this image to be loaded before the other contents are loaded

```
 <div class="overlay" id="mainoverlay">
         <div class="preloader" id="preloader">
          <img src="images/logo128.png" id="logo-preload"/> 
         </div>

     </div>
```

I want this image to be loaded before the rest of the content. In a way I want this image to load the way the browser would load a js file: block page rendering until the script is loaded. Is there any way of doing this

Comment: You can _hide_ everything else until it's loaded, but do you really want to _block_ loading?

Comment: i do hide everything else. The problem is that the logo is a little large so when the preloader comes up, the logo is still loading...which looks rather ugly

Comment: So you need a preloader for your preloader? Seems like you are solving the wrong problem. (Compress the image, or don't use an image at all.)

Comment: yes sort of. Compression still doesn't solve the problem. And the image is the logo, so need to have it. Can I force this image to load

Comment: Load a very highly compress, fuzzy version of your logo first. Then, after the nicer version of the image has completed loading, replace the highly compressed ugly version. Look at how Google Images works. When you click on an image, it shows you a blown up thumbnail that's very low quality, but if the image is still loadable, it'll load a nicer version and replace the fuzzy one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [David's imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) script, which has its use cases listed in its README.

Based on that assumption, I think you are looking for something similar to this:

```
$('#preloader').hide();
var imgLoad = imagesLoaded('#preloader');
imgLoad.on( 'always', function() {
    $('#preloader').show();
});
```